# Is it possible to use Windows Azure Mobile service with Windows 8 App which requires relational Database?

Tags: windows, xaml, azure, cloud

I am now self-studying how to developing an App for Windows 8 with C# and XAML and I want to use Windows Azure service as a cloud server for my database, just like SQL. I am new to this technology and as far as I know mobile service is not for all-purpose tools, but still, I wonder if I can use it just like SQL, in which many tables are related to each other.

If not, what Windows Azure service I should use instead? Virtual Machine, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can simplify it as Windows Azure Mobile service replaces the basic requirement basic of any currently available SQL Database access API instead using WAMS your application can connect to same SQL Database over a Mobile service endpoint available to your app and that what makes independent to any app connecting to WAMS.

WAMS simplify quick creation and access to data backend (hosted in Windows Azure) from any mobile app so yes you sure can use WAMS with SQL DB as long as you have a fixed access scope with your SQL DB requirement. When I say fixed means even when Windows Azure Mobile Service (WAMS) use SQL Database as backend you will be limited within the functionality provided within WAMS framework compare to accessing your DB over API. As you already know there are tone of other things you could do directly with SQL DB (using API or other interfaces) but not by using WAMS. However once the SQL DB is created you still can access it outside the scope of WAMS and still can do the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know it is possible to use WAMS with Win 8 app. According to your state, that there are others API which may be more suitable, which one would you recommend me to use it or study more about it?? 

I simply need to 1.)develop an App for users then I also need to 2.)develop webpage for admin and expert for database access. It would be nice to if there is any API or tools that 2 system can access the database